# How to use my index.htm in this location script?

Tags: nginx

I need URL  `http://myexample.org` (root) redirecting to my local  `index.htm`, not rewriting it to Github... How to do it?

---

I was testing many variations of `location = / { try_files ...}` but no one works. Using a UBUNTU 16 LTS server.

`/etc/nginx/sites-available/myexample.org`

```sh
server {
      server_name  myexample.org;
      root   /var/www/myexample.org;
      index  index.html index.htm;
      # ?? location =/ {...} is not working!
      location / {
            # also not work a root rewrite
            # rewrite ^/?$ index.htm break; 
            rewrite  ^/?git$
              http://github.com/myexample-org/test
              break;
            rewrite  ^/?tickets$
              http://github.com/myexample-org/test/issues
              break;
            rewrite  ^/?(.+)$
              http://github.com/myexample-org/test/$1
              break;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your last rewrite directive to match `^/(.+)$`

Answer (score 0):

`location = /` will not work for an `index`, as the rewritten URI will match `location /` which will then hit your final `rewrite` statement.

Your original solution (a few questions ago) with the named location, should work fine:

```
root /path/to/file;
index index.htm;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/... http://example.com/...;
    rewrite ^/... http://example.com/...;
    rewrite ^/... http://example.com/...;
}
```

Assuming that a file called `/path/to/file/index.htm` exists on **this** server. The `break` flag is unnecessary as the destination URL begins with `http://`. If you want to add a flag, the `redirect` or `permanent` flag would be pertinent. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.